# removing a certain part of a string in a column

Tags: r, string, dataframe

Ihave a data set and I would like to keep in one of my column only part of the string that starts with F and ends with ")" . 
this is my code:

```
    fran1[[2]] = unlist(genXtract(fran1[[2]], "F", ")"))
```

but I keep on getting this error

> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 2, value = c(`F  :  )1` = 
>        "rancisco Partners(Dipanjan Deb",  : 
>        replacement has 47 rows, data has 46

I have no idea where it comes from or how to fix it.

Comment: Look at your data, probably you have 1 row with 2 parts starting with 'F' and ending with ')'

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `gsub()`

```
gsub("(.*)(F.*\\))(.*)","\\2","asdfFrancisco)")

"Francisco)"
```

Here we are capturing all the string until an `F` is found. We capture the following string until a `)` is reached and thats all we keep.

Comment: thank you but there is a problem my out put should look like this :Francisco Partners(x) , but it returns only "Francisco)" how can i fix it

Comment: if I feed it something like `asdfFrancisco Partners(x)asdf` it does return `Francisco Partners(x)`